# Generating new SHA1 fingerprint

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1

I've encountered an issue with my keystore, and in a string of poor decisions have deleted my debug from my console developer account. I've now reach the point where I need to publish but the sha1 fingerprint is used by the former game. I need to know whether its possible to generate a new sha1 fingerprint within the same project or if i have to create a new project and migrate everything over.

Comment: You want debug SHA1 Fingerprint or Release version?

Comment: I have the SHA1 fingerprint, but I lost the password for the keystore that I had created when doing the debug. Now that I'm at the point where I am releasing it, I cannot create a new debug and app release because the package and sha1 are associated with the apk that I have uploaded prior. I've also ill-advisedly deleted the debug version from play developer console.

Comment: If you lost the keystore then you have to create a new which cannot be created like the old one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps

click on gradle on right top>android>task>android>signingReport and you will found your SHA-1 in the run signing report..

Comment: sha1 can not be changed for computer if you want to change you need to get another computer.

Comment: oh, so the sha1 is connected to my computer, and will always be the same regardless of what project it creates?